# How do I pre-configure SSH key on a new workstation?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, iso

I want to manage installs and updates on a park of Ubuntu nodes using Ansible.

### What is the issue ?

If I want to connect to other nodes using Ansible, I need SSH access to them. Which means I need to share my pub_key. I would like to automate that process for a brand new workstation setup.

### What did I try so far ?

I've thought about shifting the initial .iso installer (using Cubic) and add an `admin_user`. This way I could connect to the managed node using this admin's user access and configure the ssh key. However, the user's installation process get overwritten by my user, and the machine ends up with only the `admin_user`, whilst the user created during the installation process is ignored.

Thanks in advance